# Serving a Spring Boot Actuator endpoint on multiple ports

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Our main application is being served on port 8443, and we're using `management.port` to serve our actuator endpoints on port 8444.

Is there a way to get a single endpoint (the health endpoint) to serve on both 8443 and 8444 while leaving the remaining endpoints on port 8444 only?

Comment: Typically, people put Apache HTTPD (with mod_proxy) or ngnix in front of their Spring Boot app. Those pieces of software are really good at this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Providing you're using the built in Tomcat container you could:

1. Remove the management port config property
2. Add an additional connector to serve port 8444
3. Add a filter to allow only the health check be accessed on that port

Your code might look something like this.

```java
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    private PortInterceptor portInterceptor;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(portInterceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory)container;
        Connector connector = new Connector();
        connector.setPort(8444);
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
    }
}

@Component
public class PortInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if(request.getLocalPort() == 8444){
            return isHealthCheckRequest(request);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Small remark I took `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` with `import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` instead of `WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` which made me to implement an additional constructor with lots of parameters.