# How to ignore some path with Spring Security and SSL?

Tags: ssl, spring-security

This is my Spring configuration:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class X509Configuration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ws/items.wsdl");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                 .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers("/ws/items.wsdl").permitAll()
                 .and()
            // require authorization for everything else
            .authorizeRequests()
                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
                 .and()
            .x509()
                 .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                 .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                 .and()
            .csrf().disable()

            // configure form login
            .formLogin().disable()

            // configure logout
            .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
                if (username.equals("cid")) {
                    return new User(username, "",
                        AuthorityUtils
                                .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
                }
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

These are SSL settings:

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: 'classpath:keystore.jks'
    key-store-password: 'changeit'
    key-password: 'changeit'
    trust-store: 'classpath:truststore.jks'
    trust-store-password: 'changeit'
    client-auth: need
```

What I want is to ignore for SSL or to permit for all my WSDL site.
But with this configuration it doesn't work. I get following error:

> http https://localhost:8443/ws/items.wsdl http: error: SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) while doing GET request to URL: https://localhost:8443/ws/items.wsdl

I don't want to use ca signed certificates. (With signed certificates it works.)
How can I do this? What options do I have?

Comment: No. I have only https connector and would like to allow my WSDL be insecure accessible. If it doesn't work, I can open a new HTTP connection like it's described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36623801/1648825.

Comment: I am stuck here as well, how come no one knows how to solve it. I have one api to exclude from x509 authentication and I just can't find a way to do it. Spend 2 days to research on it already!!

Answer (score -2):

Remove this :

```
.authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers("/ws/items.wsdl").permitAll()
```

The web config is saying ignore that path, yet your http security is saying to make requests to that path go through auth.

Comment: It doesn't help. In browser I get `localhost:8443 uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`
and with http cli:                                                                                  
`http https://localhost:8443/ws/items.wsdl` `http: error: SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) while doing GET request to URL: https://localhost:8443/ws/items.wsdl`