# Ignore ssl.client-auth for specific endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

### Background

I am using client-server mutual authentication (mTLS) for the app authentication.

```
# application.properties
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3
server.ssl.client-auth=need

# ... and key-stores configurations
```

### Problem

I got several APIs working fine with this config. However, for some specific APIs I would like them to be public. i.e. mTLS is not required for these APIs.

I went though Google and surprisingly there isn't much about disabling it for specific paths. Most, if not all, are about `HttpSecurity`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) 
        throws Exception {

        http.cors(cors -> cors.disable())
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/hello")
                .permitAll();
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The API `/hello` is supposed to be public, whereas `/secret` needs client-auth. The above filter chain does not apply to client-auth and I cannot `GET /hello` without a client certificate.

### How I test it:

```bash
curl https://localhost:8080/hello -k -v --cert ./client.cert --key ./client.key
```

where

- `-k` ignores server cert as it is self-signed
- `-v` for verbose output
- `--cert` and `--key` is the client certificate and key

With cert and key,

```bash
$ curl https://localhost:8080/hello -k --cert ./client.cert --key ./client.key
Hello
```

Without the cert and key,

```bash
$ curl https://localhost:8080/hello -k
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate, errno 0
```

### What I tried

- I tried setting `server.ssl.client-auth=want` or `none` and it works for `GET /hello`, so does `GET /secret`...
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40492809/6625422) question but there are no answers
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70589592/6625422) doesn't seem related

### Question

Is there a way to ignore client certificate authentication for some paths while enforcing client-auth for the rest of paths?

### Version

- Spring boot version: 2.7.7 (migrate to v3 is on the list)
- Java: 17

---

## Edit 1

Thanks @dur for your comment. I just tried having 2 filter chains and set `client-auth=want`.

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain publicApiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello").permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain privateApiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .authenticated().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .x509()
            .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    return http.build();
}
```

```java
@Bean
UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) {
            log.info("UserDetailsService username={}", username);

            if (username == null || username.length() == 0) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
            }

            User user = new User(username, "", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_SSL_USER"));
            return user;
        }
    };
}
```

But after a bit of tweaks, I still cannot manage to allow `GET /hello` for public and `GET /secret` for private. I can either make them all public or all private. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing 2 way SSL using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808603/implementing-2-way-ssl-using-spring-boot)

Comment: You could use `server.ssl.client-auth=want` and then configure `x509()` in your filter chain. For the permitted URLs, you could use a second filter chain without `x509()`.

Comment: You didn't restrict your filter chains, so the first one is applied for every request. You have to restrict and order the filter chains, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298001/how-to-use-multiple-login-pages-one-for-admin-and-the-other-one-for-user/75303651#75303651

Comment: Yeah that's it. I thought the `antMatchers` after `authorizeRequests` is enough. BTW `http.securityMatcher` does not exist until Spring 6. In Spring 5 `antMatcher` is used. At least that works for me :D

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You need to do 2 more things to get it working:

1. Set order for your mTLS filter chain:

`@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
SecurityFilterChain privateApiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {`

2. Replace `.antMatchers("/**")` with specific endpoint pattern matchers.